# Outlook 2016 for Mac: Column View with Reading Pane on right

Tags: ms-office

How do you get the reading pane on the right while retaining a column view of emails in the centre?

Whenever I turn on the reading pane to show on the right side, the email list changes from Column View to a format I don't like, which shows each mail over a number of lines that includes a preview.  (I'm not sure what the name of this view is.)

On Outlook for the PC, this is not a problem, but on Mac it is for some reason?

Answer (score 2):

You don't. This is a behaviour/design feature that Microsoft has seen fit to omit/break between their Windows and macOS versions of the product. There have been requests to resolve this, since Office 2013, however Microsoft are not listening or don't care.